# Stored Procedure with Exception Handling at No_Data_Found for Delete and Update

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle10g, delete-row

I hope anybody can check and correct my not working coding. I know that there is a particular Thing with the no_data_found exception because it only works with an Into Statement. But how works an exception with delete or update when no data found?

```
create or replace procedure del
(p_per_no in Table.per_no%type)
is 
begin
delete from TABLE
where per_no = p_per_no;
if SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 then raise my_exception;
end if;
exception
when my_exception then dbms_output.put_line('no data found');
end del;
/
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your code is correct. But you missed declaring the my_exception.

```
my_exception exception;
```